# Is there a way to set the text of a multipart node using \tikzset?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In order to create a parameterized split node, I would like to use arguments in the node parts.

Here is what I did:

```
\tikzset{threeParts/.style n args={3}{%
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal, 
    rectangle split parts=3,
    draw,
    whichKeyShouldIuseHere={
     nodepart{one} {#1}
     nodepart{two} {#2}
     nodepart{three} {#3}},
 }}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path  node[threeParts={1,2,3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but this does not work, and I could not find the correct key to be used for filling in the curly brackets of the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer requires the CVS version on sourceforge. (*Thanks Torbjørn*)**

The key you are looking for is the `node contents` key.
It allows your specific need.

You use it like this:

```
node contents={<content of node>}

\node[node contents=ABC];
```

notice that you should not provide an additional content specifier for nodes using the above construct.

So in your case you find:

```
\tikzset{threeParts/.style n args={3}{%
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal, 
        rectangle split parts=3,
        draw,
        node contents={#1\nodepart{two}#2\nodepart{three}#3}
    }
}
```

And your `tikzpicture` becomes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[threeParts={Part 1}{Part 2}{Part 3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Notice you had it slightly wrong with 3 arguments for the parts.
If you want to use commas do this instead:

```
threePartsComma/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{<previous content>}
```

and use:

```
node[threePartsComma={Hell,o and,welcome}];
```

Here it will be very wise to always use the brace around the full argument as `tikz` options are parsed by comma's.

Remark that you can not use the `node[node contents=< >] at (0,0);` construct, the placement should be performed either in the options of the node or via the `\path (0,0) node[...];`.

A small picture:

[image]

Comment: Is the `node contents` key new in version 3 of `pgf`/TikZ? It doesn't exist in 2.10 at least (that found in a newly updated TeX Live 2013).

Comment: I have actually not checked this, but yes, I am using a very recent version. So this could be limited to a recent version of `pgf`. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Dear zeroth, I'm not able to reproduce your result. My generated image show only 'Part 1'. Please, can you provide complete example starting with \documentclass and ending by \end{document}? I like to se, what I doing wrong ...

Comment: @Zarko are you using the latest pgf (I haven't seen your comment as you haven't used the <at> command)