# Parameterize the node texts in tikzset

Tags: tikzset

I have the following code which draws a linked list

Initially it printed the node texts as leaning against the right edges of the nodes. Putting `\hspace*{-3pt}` in front each text solves this horizontal misalignment problem.

[image: linkedlist-in-tikz]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,chains,positioning,arrows,calc,arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\columnratio}{0.62} % to be able to fit the TikZ drawing
\newcommand{\columnseper}{12pt} % inside small sections

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ourwidth}{\columnratio * \linewidth - \columnseper}

\tikzset{thebox/.style = {
    % args={2}, % Nope
    rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    very thick, draw=black!100,
    align=center,font=\footnotesize,
    text width=0.047 * \ourwidth,
    minimum width=0.040 * \ourwidth,
    text height=0.023 * \ourwidth,
    text depth=2.7pt,
    inner xsep=0.30cm,
    % inner xsep west = 0.10cm % Nope
    node distance = 4mm,
% \nodepart[]{one} text = {\hspace*{-3pt}#1}, % Attempt to parameterize the text
% \nodepart[]{two} text = {\hspace*{-3pt}#2},
} }

\tikzset{arr/.style = {very thick,{Circle[length=6pt,sep=-3pt]}-{Stealth} } }
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=1,start chain=2,start chain=3,start chain=4]
\tikzset{every node}=[font=\small\ttfamily]
      
\node[rectangle, on chain=1,inner xsep=0.05cm,](ORIG){\footnotesize 1511};

\node (A) [thebox,on chain=1,right=0.0cm of ORIG]
     {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}1111 \nodepart[]{two}}; % comment \hspace*{-3pt}1111

\node (B) [thebox, on chain=1,] % right=0.4cm of A,
     {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt} \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}};

\node (C) [thebox, on chain=1,] % right=0.4cm of B,
     {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}2111 \nodepart[]{two}};

\node (D) [thebox, on chain=1,] % right=0.4cm of C
     {\nodepart[]{one} \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}0000};

\node (E) [thebox, on chain=3,below=0.55cm of D] at (9.65, -0.3)
     {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}6700 \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}};

\node (F) [thebox, on chain=3,] % right=0.4 of E
     {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}8000 \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}0000};
     
\node (G) [thebox, on chain=2,below=1.4cm of B] at (4.6, -0.5)
      {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}3422 \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}};

\node (H) [thebox, on chain=2,] %at (4.5, -0.5) % right=0.4cm of G
     {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt} \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}};

\node (I) [thebox, on chain=4,below=0.6cm of H] at (7.6, -2.5)
      {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}4000 \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}};

\node (J) [thebox, on chain=2,] % right=0.4cm of H 
      {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}5321 \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}0000};
      
\node (K) [thebox, on chain=4,] % right=0.4cm of I
     {\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}7222 \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}0000};


 \draw[arr] ($(A.two)!0.32!(A.east)$) -- (B.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(B.west)!0.10!(B.east)$) |- (G.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(B.two)!0.32!(B.east)$) -- (C.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(C.two)!0.32!(C.east)$) -- (D.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(D.west)!0.10!(D.east)$) |- (E.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(E.two)!0.32!(E.east)$) -- (F.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(G.two)!0.32!(G.east)$) -- (H.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(H.west)!0.08!(H.east)$) |- (I.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(H.two)!0.32!(H.east)$) -- (J.west);
 \draw[arr] ($(I.two)!0.32!(I.east)$) -- (K.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In order to avoid manual repetition, I consider parameterizing the node text in  `tikzset=thebox/.style{...`
I've added

```
  \nodepart[]{one} text = {\hspace*{-3pt} #1 }
  \nodepart[]{two} text = {\hspace*{-3pt} #2}
```

not surprisingly they didn't work. I've looked up similar posts like this one
[Is there a way to set the text of a multipart node using \tikzset?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152111/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-text-of-a-multipart-node-using-tikzset)

and I've added `n args={2}` next to `thebox/.style` but this caused compile error. I've looked up the TikZ manual, which is over 1300 pages (!) and no clear example about this particular problem.

How to correctly parameterize the node text inside the `\tikzset` ?

Comment: On most problems mention here you got (in addendum to the answer) in the https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642453/adjusting-the-starting-coordinates-of-an-arrow-precisely-inside-a-tikz-node/642542#642542

Comment: Would it be easier to define another command, for example `\newcommand{\nodetext}[2]{\nodepart[]{one}\hspace*{-3pt}#1 \nodepart[]{two}\hspace*{-3pt}#2}`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. When I tried that new command, using e.g. `\nodetext{8000,0000}` or `\nodetext[8000,0000]` compiler gave `!Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.` error on both cases. How to use it? Besides, I prefer a version of that command which don't include the `{one}` and `{two}` expressions in it because in other sections of the book I use other names other there.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen I think it should be used as `\nodetext{8000}{8000}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the node text using `node contents`, e.g.

```
\tikzset{thebox/.style n args={2}{
        node contents={\nodepart{one}\hspace*{-3pt}#1\nodepart{two}\hspace*{-3pt}#2},
    }
}
```

and then `\node (C) [thebox={2111}{},on chain=1];`.

---

Here is a MWE based on your code. I allowed myself to do some modifications to make it shorter. The box size is determined only by `text width` and `minimum height`. You don't need `\hspace*{-3pt}` here. Also, for every box I define two coordinates `x-one` and `x-two` to simplify the arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,chains,positioning,arrows.meta,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{thebox/.style n args={2}{
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        very thick,
        draw=black,
        align=center,
        text width=25, % adjust box width here
        minimum height=18, % adjust box height here
        node distance=4mm,
        node contents={\nodepart{one}#1\nodepart{two}#2},
        append after command={% define x-one and x-two coordinates for connecting arrows
            \pgfextra{\edef\currentnode{\tikzlastnode}}
            (\currentnode.two north|-\currentnode.east) coordinate (\currentnode-two)
            ($(\currentnode.west)!0.1!(\currentnode.east)$) coordinate (\currentnode-one)
        },
    },
    arr/.style={very thick,{Circle[length=6pt,sep=-3pt]}-{Stealth}},
    every node/.append style={font=\footnotesize\ttfamily},
}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=1,start chain=2,start chain=3,start chain=4]

\node[rectangle,on chain=1,inner xsep=0.05cm,] (ORIG) {1511};

\node (A) [thebox={1111}{},on chain=1,right=0.0cm of ORIG];
\node (B) [thebox={}{},on chain=1];
\node (C) [thebox={2111}{},on chain=1];
\node (D) [thebox={}{0000},on chain=1];
\node (E) [thebox={6700}{},on chain=3,below right=0.55cm and 0.75cm of D.south west];
\node (F) [thebox={8000}{0000},on chain=3];
\node (G) [thebox={3422}{},on chain=2,below right=1.4cm and 0.75cm of B.south west];
\node (H) [thebox={}{},on chain=2];
\node (I) [thebox={4000}{},on chain=4,below right=0.6cm and 0.75cm of H.south west];
\node (J) [thebox={5321}{0000},on chain=2];
\node (K) [thebox={7222}{0000},on chain=4];

\draw[arr] (A-two) -- (B);
\draw[arr] (B-two) -- (C);
\draw[arr] (C-two) -- (D);
\draw[arr] (D-one) |- (E);
\draw[arr] (E-two) -- (F);
\draw[arr] (B-one) |- (G);
\draw[arr] (G-two) -- (H);
\draw[arr] (H-one) |- (I);
\draw[arr] (I-two) -- (K);
\draw[arr] (H-two) -- (J);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the problem is caused by too-narrow `text width` with settings `align=center, inner xsep=0.30cm`. With enough width, for example `text width=1cm`, the output looks fine (hence there's no need for `\hspace{-3pt}`).

Additionally, to start the arrow rightly from the center of node part `two`, I've changed every

```tex
\draw[arr] ($(X.two)!0.32!(A.east)$) -- (Y.west);
```

to

```tex
\draw[arr] ($(X.one split)!0.5!(A.east)$) -- (Y.west);
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,chains,positioning,arrows,calc,arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\columnratio}{0.62} % to be able to fit the TikZ drawing
\newcommand{\columnseper}{12pt} % inside small sections

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ourwidth}{\columnratio * \linewidth - \columnseper}

\tikzset{
  thebox/.style = {
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    very thick,
    draw=black!100,
    align=center,
    text width=1cm,
    text height=1.5ex,
    text depth=.35ex,
    inner xsep=0.08cm,
    node distance=2mm and 4mm,
  },
  arr/.style = {
    very thick,
    {Circle[length=6pt,sep=-3pt]}-{Stealth},
  },
}


\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain/.list={1,2,3,4},
  nodes={font=\footnotesize\ttfamily}]
  
  \node[on chain=1] (ORIG) {1511};
  
  \node (A) [thebox, on chain=1, right=0cm of ORIG]
       {\nodepart{one}1111 \nodepart{two}};
  
  \node (B) [thebox, on chain=1,] % right=0.4cm of A,
       {\nodepart[]{one} \nodepart[]{two}};
  
  \node (C) [thebox, on chain=1,] % right=0.4cm of B,
       {\nodepart[]{one} 2111 \nodepart[]{two}};
  
  \node (D) [thebox, on chain=1,] % right=0.4cm of C
       {\nodepart[]{one} \nodepart[]{two} 0000};
  
  \node (E) [thebox, on chain=3, below right=.3cm and -1.5cm of D]
       {\nodepart[]{one} 6700 \nodepart[]{two}};
  
  \node (F) [thebox, on chain=3,] % right=0.4 of E
       {\nodepart[]{one} 8000 \nodepart[]{two} 0000};
       
  \node (G) [thebox, on chain=2, below right=1.3cm and -1.5cm of B]
        {\nodepart[]{one} 3422 \nodepart[]{two} };
  
  \node (H) [thebox, on chain=2,] %at (4.5, -0.5) % right=0.4cm of G
       {\nodepart[]{one} \nodepart[]{two} };
  
  \node (I) [thebox, on chain=4, below right=0.3cm and -1.3cm of H]
        {\nodepart[]{one} 4000 \nodepart[]{two}};
  
  \node (J) [thebox, on chain=2,] % right=0.4cm of H 
        {\nodepart[]{one} 5321 \nodepart[]{two} 0000};
        
  \node (K) [thebox, on chain=4,] % right=0.4cm of I
       {\nodepart[]{one} 7222 \nodepart[]{two} 0000};


   \draw[arr] ($(A.one split)!0.5!(A.east)$) -- (B.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(B.west)!0.10!(B.east)$) |- (G.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(B.one split)!0.5!(B.east)$) -- (C.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(C.one split)!0.5!(C.east)$) -- (D.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(D.west)!0.10!(D.east)$) |- (E.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(E.one split)!0.5!(E.east)$) -- (F.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(G.one split)!0.5!(G.east)$) -- (H.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(H.west)!0.10!(H.east)$) |- (I.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(H.one split)!0.5!(H.east)$) -- (J.west);
   \draw[arr] ($(I.one split)!0.5!(I.east)$) -- (K.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To parameterize the text of node parts, in theory you can add options `execute at begin node` and `execute at end node` to styles `every <part name> node part`, like

```tex
every one node part/.style={
  execute at begin node=...,
  execute at end node=...
}
```

But currently there's a bug that `execute at end node` is executed twice for the first node part, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1155.